# jQuery ajax call return 302

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I searched and there are a few similar post like this on forum but I still could not solve my problem.

The project I am working on is ASP.NET WebForms. On my default.aspx, I make a ajax GET request to page method, inside this method I simply return back to client by writing Response.Write

The problem is it works properly at local which uses HTTP protocol.
But when I deploy it to my server which uses HTTPS protocol, AJAX request returns 302 code(similar to other posts).

The urls for default page and for ajax request are something like:
**https:///default.aspx** and **https:///ajax.aspx?action=something**

So I believe this is not cross domain issue.

This is the weird part, when I tried to set up my site at local to run on HTTPS, it works property. I also tried solutions from other posts but no luck.

My local is running on **Win 8.1, IIS 8**, my server is running on **Win 2k3, IIS 6**

Will there be any issue because of that?

What do you suggest me to look at next, any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the Redirect is HTTP or HTTPS ???

Comment: Yes, it was HTTPS being redirected to HTTP

Comment: make sure that your Redirection is go to HTTP and your request is not HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

```
** UPDATE ANSWER **
```

Such a silly mistake, I thought the whole website runs under HTTPS.

My default page is under HTTPS **but my ajax endpoint does not**

So the obvious solution is make ajax endpoint runs under **HTTPS** or create method call in default page and invoke it instead.

I chose the first option.

Comment: I had the same problem.